# How can I ignore test failures with the gradle robolectric plugin?

Tags: android, gradle, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I'm using the [robolectric-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin) for robolectric unit tests.  I don't want to fail a build on failed tests.  Is there a way in DSL or a property not to fail a test on the build similar to `-DtestFailureIgnore=true` on the Surefire Maven plugin?

I've tried:

```
robolectric {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

and

```
robolectric {
    ignoreFailure = true
}
```

and `-DignoreFailure=true` on the command line.

I can't seem to find any documentation of how to do this, or any reference to ignoring tests in the source code.

Comment: If the failed tests set is small you can mark them @Ignore to fix times

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142486/dont-fail-the-gradle-build-if-a-test-is-failing-with-the-gradle-android-test-pl/25587012#25587012 Follow this link.And it may help you.

Answer (score 14):

answering very old question, so that it might help others who bump into here

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        setIgnoreFailures(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you be able to add a reference to the documentation for this please?

Comment: @Dezza no trace of documentation for this property. I have gone through the gradle version 1.5.0 source code and found this solution. Property _ignoreFailures_ is defined in `Test.java`, which is accessible via `UnitTestOptions.all()` of `TestOptions.java`

Comment: after i found out, where to set this, i m thankful for your answer!
`android {

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            setIgnoreFailures(true)
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to continue building an APK if there are any failing tests. But if you want to build an APK without testing the only way right now is to use gradle build -x test[1]. This will run build and not run any tests.

[1][http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:excluding_tasks_from_the_command_line](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3aexcluding_tasks_from_the_command_line)

Comment: The reason to continue the build, is if other things will run later against the APK.  For example: Integration tests, FindBugs, Reports etc.  Stopping too soon could prevent these.

Answer (score 0):

try without '='

```
robolectric {
    ignoreFailures true
}
```

Comment: jermaine1904, how to use it in new Android Studio 1.1.0 for example with Robolectric 3.0. From last updates we don't use plugin, so the code above doesn't work?

Comment: do you run your tests in android studio or via console?

Comment: jermaine1904@ in Android Studio, tab Terminal (like from usual console, how I understand)