# continue jacoco code coverage report after fail test case

Tags: android, junit, android-studio, android-testing, jacoco

Code coverage report not generated when Test case failed in android studio using Jacoco plugin.How to skip failed test case and generate code coverage report.

Comment: Did u got the solution to generate the coverage report when test case fails?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142486/dont-fail-the-gradle-build-if-a-test-is-failing-with-the-gradle-android-test-pl/25587012#25587012 This may help you. Follow the above link

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this flag when running your test

`-Djacoco.haltOnFailure=false`

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code in `Build.gradle(Module:app)`:

```
android {

 testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        setIgnoreFailures(true)
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to add a little bit of commentary to this answer, to explain how it answers the question, and what side-effects there might be. For example, does `setIgnoreFailures(true)` only apply to the coverage report, or does it mean that a build will be considered successful even with failed builds?

Comment: is it working if i try this this didn't worked for me

Answer (score -3):

If you just need to get the report you can add the `@Ignore` above the tests in order to temporarily skip them.
When you take care of the reason these tests fail then you just remove the annotation.

This annotation will not run any of the marked tests, you can use it either at class file or at the method/test.

Comment: @Ignore is used to skip the class, not to generate coverage report, when any of the class fails in the test suite.